# Customizing a get URL in routes.rb file gives undefined method {symbol}_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3 and ruby 1.9

I'm trying to create a customized URL for a resource that I call **BasicQuery**, but I think my **routes.rb** file is not written correctly.  Details below.

For the sake of simplicity BasicQuery comes in 2 flavors (a or b)

I'd like to customize the URL for BasicQuery in 2 ways:

- I'd like the URL to indicate which "flavor" of basic query is being requested (a or b)
- The controller for BasicQuery is called basic_queries_controller, but I'd like the URL to be more intuitive (at least to me) and I'd like to have the "prefix" portion of the URL be "basic_query" instead of "basic_queries"

So, if I am going to create a new BasicQuery of flavor "a", my get URL would be:

```
http://localhost:3000/basic_query/a
```

If I'm going to create a new BasicQuery of flavor "b", my get URL would be:

```
http://localhost:3000/basic_query/b
```

my **routes.rb** file entry looks like this:

```
get "basic_query/:flavor" => "basic_queries#new"
```

my basic_queries_controller.rb file looks like this:

```
  def new
    @basic_query = BasicQuery.new(flavor: params[:flavor])
  end
```

my view (new.html.haml) looks like this:

```
= form_for(@basic_query) do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :search_term
    %br
    = f.text_field :search_term
    %br
    = f.hidden_field :flavor
  .actions
    = f.submit
```

However, when I request the following URL: http://localhost:3000/a, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `basic_queries_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000010294f068>:0x0000010290eb58>

= form_for(@basic_query) do |f|  # <= this is the problematic line!
  .field
    = f.label :search_term
    %br
```

So, I assume my routes.rb file doesn't properly define the **basic_queries_path**, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb`, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use form_for, you need to define a "POST" method, that the form can submit to, at the moment you are only setting up a GET for returning the form that you then will fill in.

In your routes.rb file you need to do something like this:

`post "/basic_query", :as => "basic_queries"`

or

`match "/basic_query", :to => "basic_queries#create", :via => :post, :as => "basic_queries"`

That should do it.